# Problem with texture. uv

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]I don't understand how need to repair this mistake. Please help. [image]

Comment: The best is probably to mark seams along the good edges and unwrap again, but maybe show your UV Editor so that we see how your UVs look like and how they are placed on your texture

Comment: I added uv/////.

Comment: what method have you used? Your UVs are probably not proportional to the faces. Maybe pack the image (File > External Data > Pack Resources), save and share your file (only keep the sofa), once you've uploaded the file, copy paste the URL it has generated: pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Can i ask how need to save only sofa?

Comment: I mean you don't need to share the rest of your file, if you don't want to, or if it's too heavy for pasteall

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/59e4def36fcf4ec7a213d03ab8bd3d14

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the *Subdivision Surface* modifier which stretches your faces. The fastest way to fix it is probably to add edges, like these ones (I've reunwrapped with the *Smart UV Project* mode to make the UVs proportional to the faces though):

[image]

The cleanest way would be to mark some seam where real seams are supposed to be on real sofas, then unwrap again with the simple *Unwrap* option, but, depending on your final picture, it may be enough to just use the first solution.

Comment: Thank you so much!